# QML Change Gradient when Button is Pressed

Tags: android, qt, styles, qml

I need my button to changed gradient when pressed.
I've tried the following code (suggested by official documentation):

```
Button {
  background: Rectangle {
    gradient: Gradient {
      GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: control.pressed ? "#ccc" : "#eee" }
      GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: control.pressed ? "#aaa" : "#ccc" }
    }
  }
}
```

However, my button turns out black.
By substituing the word 'control' with the word 'this' or 'parent', I get the same result: the button is correctly coloured in case it is not pressed, but when I press it, nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to give your button an `id:control`.

`this.pressed` and `parent.pressed` will be `undefined`, which means they will resolve to `false`.